# Bash script detect received iMessage along with its contents?

Tags: applescript, messages, bash, contacts

I've been doing some searching around online for an answer to this question and can't seem to find one. My aim is to run a bash script which waits for the arrival of an iMessage from a specific contact and when the message is received, it inputs the content of the iMessage into a specified command.

I understand that whatever the command is (if there is one) to check for the presence of a new message from a specified contact will probably have to be repeated in some sort of loop but for now, I am just wondering if there is some sort of command (maybe osascript) which can check for this?

E.g.

iMessage: From, Tom: Hello World

```
echo "$imessagemessage" > ~/Desktop/message.txt
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? If so, I would really appreciate it if someone could give me some guidance.

Thank you in advance,

Kind regards,

Tom

Comment: Your going to have to check the database with SQL Lite prob

Comment: @JBis Thanks for your reply,  was considering that but thought it would be rather inefficient. Any suggestions on how to best integrate this with a Bash script?

Comment: Read this https://github.com/ZekeSnider/Jared/issues/20

Comment: @JBis Just had a read through and tried the AppleScript that "mezeipetister" suggested but can't seem to get that working due to Syntax Errors. Any advice? I've also read this guide: https://hackernoon.com/a-crude-imessage-api-efed29598e61 but it seems that this is now obsolete due to it being designed for older operating systems.

Answer (score 1):

I've come across the following Python3 project as well called imessage_reader via https://pypi.org/project/imessage-reader/

Comment: Interesting find. Wonder how this can be used to solve the problem described in the question.